# Sammy.js showing error

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, sammy.js

I have created a page using knockout and Sammy in asp.net 3.5. I have put jquery,knockout.js and Sammy.js in aspx page.

But its showing me error that 
"**ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
--> })(jQuery, window);**"

And my sammy version is 0.6.3.

What should i do to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you put jquery before all scripts?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually jquery should be put before sammy.js and after that it works fine.